# Android device can't instantiate launcher activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, launcher

When I try run my current android project on my phone, after successfully build and deploy it, I am getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15869): Process: org.hello, PID: 15869
E/AndroidRuntime(15869): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.hello/org.hello.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hello.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.hello-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.hello-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hello.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.hello-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.hello-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
E/AndroidRuntime(15869):        ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  916):   Force finishing activity org.hello/.MainActivity
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the main activity is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"), Tab1Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"), Tab2Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"), Tab3Fragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

and the source code for this class and others are all placed in the directory src/main/java/org/hello from my project.

Anyone knows what is causing this error?

**UPDATE 1**

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-tabs</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <android.sdk.path>/home/kleber/android-sdk-linux/</android.sdk.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
           <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
           <version>20.0.0</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>/home/kleber/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>/home/kleber/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to clean the project.

Comment: @Hegazy i try this, but don't solve the problem.

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest`, try replacing the activity from `android:name=".MainActivity"` to `android:name="org.hello.MainActivity"`

Comment: If its stored in`src/main/java/org/hello`, should the package be `main.java.org.hello` instead of `org.hello`?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri it's a maven project. In the class, the package is declared as org.hello. The src/main/java is part of the structure of the project.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I try that too, don't solve the problem either.

Comment: okay. Have you defined `applicationId "org.hello"`in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri not using gradle, but maven. pom.xml added to the question (see update 1).

Comment: Ohh, yaa. You told earlier that you are using maven. I should go and get a coffee now.

Comment: I added the maven tag. This is a maven config problem, not a code problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did not properly set up the java source and resource folder, so maven does not find them in the places where they are supposed to. By default maven assumes the source folder is in `/src`, which would make compile your class to `main.java.org.hello.MainActivity` and this is why it cannot be found.

You should add something like this to your maven build file:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/res</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

see full answer: [Changing the Maven structure ( src/java to src/Javasource)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955359/changing-the-maven-structure-src-java-to-src-javasource)

Comment: But the project is built correctly by maven, only when I run in my phone I get the error (I build another project with maven with this same structure without problem. the unqiue difference to this current project is that I include de android support library and the code for the classes).

Comment: Your project might be building, but did you check whether the source files are actually compiled. Take a look at the `/target` folder and see if all your class files are compiled and packaged. It might be that maven only picks up your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Just a guess...