# Placing the ActionBar.Tabs on the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I recently implemented a simple project which uses ActionBar.Tabs. the main activity have this implementation:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3;

    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new Tab3Fragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
        Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3");

        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void openSearch() {
      //
    }

    public void openSettings() {
      //
    }

}
```

and the layout associated to this activity is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

when I run the project on my phone, the tabs are placed on the top of the screen, below the actiobBar itself. I want place this tabs on the bottom of screen. Anyone can tell me a way to do this?

ps.: I actually try that using a layout which use TabHost, TabWidget and Fragments, but I am  getting the error described here: [Android device can't instantiate launcher activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919638/android-device-cant-instantiate-launcher-activity)

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in Android 5.0, and that Android design guidelines say that tabs belong at the top, not the bottom.

Comment: @CommonsWare despite the Android desgin guidelines, I want the tabs in a place of easy access to the user, to allow use with one hand. Like most of the popular apps for Android do. Any ideas in how to accomplish this, putting aside this recommendations from google?

Comment: "Like most of the popular apps for Android do" -- you are welcome to your opinion; [UX experts would disagree with you](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/07/tabs-top-or-bottom.html). "Any ideas in how to accomplish this" -- use something other than action bar tabs. Any other tab solution at least gives you options for positioning the tabs; action bar tabs do not (unless there's some theme option for it that I've missed).